# jQuery UI Autocomplete JSON array vs. JS-Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, user-interface, autocomplete

Hoi folks, i am not confirm to js. My Problem ist if i define an array for autocomplete in the code it works, if i use an json-array( also from an external source) it dosent. What am i doing wrong ?

```
 jsonData='{"kantone":["VD","FR","GE"]}
 var alternate=["TG","ZG","ZH"];
 window.availableKanton = JSON.parse(jsonData);
 $(function() {
 $( "#startkanton" ).autocomplete({
   source: window.availableKanton.kantone // dont work if i take the alternate it does

   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I pasted your code into the snippet below, and it's working.

The only thing I had to do was to close the string (by putting a `'`) into the first line.

```js
var jsonData = '{"kantone":["VD","FR","GE"]}';
var alternate = ["TG", "ZG", "ZH"];

window.availableKanton = JSON.parse(jsonData);

$(function() {
  $("#startkanton").autocomplete({
    source: window.availableKanton.kantone // working
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="startkanton">
```